# Filter data of a specific column through pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Clean the YrsExp column
This column can contain many dirty values.
After clean up, all this column should contain is a number that represents number of years.
For example, any years > 10 should be replaced by 10,
and any value in months should be replaced by 0.

This column can contain these values:

```
['7 MONTH' '5 MONTHS' nan '2 YEARS' '1 YEAR' '6 MONTHS' '3 YEARS'
 '2 MONTHS' '5 YEAR' '7 MONTHS' '3 YEAR' '2 YEAR' '6 YEARS' '7 YEARS'
 '4 MONTHS' '4' '6' '7' '2' '8' '15' '5' '10 YEAR' '8 year' '25 YEARS' '3'
 '1' '1YEAR' '5 YEARS' '1 YERS' '06 MONTHS' '05 YEARS' '03 YEARS'
 '04 MONTHS' '02 YEARS' '03 MONTHS' '02 MONTHS' '01 YEARS' '4 YEARS' '10'
 '13' '3YEAR' '6YRS.' '5YRS.' '4YRS.' '7YRS.' '10YRS.' '9YRS.' '3 MOTH'
 '5 MONTH' '20' '6 YEAR' '33' '18' '11' '4 YEAR' '6 Month' '2 MONTH'
 '15 YEAR' '25' '40' '19' '27' '7 YEAR' '17 YEAR' '8 YEAR' '9 YEAR'
 '15 YEARS' '3 MONTH' '11 MONTHS' '6 MONTH' '11 YEARS' '10 YEARS'
 '12 YEARS' '8 MONTH' '9' '30' '12' '4 MONTH' '5 YERS' '3साल' '10साल'
 '1साल' '7साल' '5साल' '3 माह' '2 माह' '3 साल' '2 साल' '4साल' '2साल'
 '18साल' '30साल' '11साल' '40साल' '12साल' '6माह' '3माह' '13साल' '8साल'
 '3 वर्ष' '10 वर्ष' '8 माह' '7 वर्ष' '9वर्श' '3 बर्ष' '5 वर्ष' '5 माह'
 '8 वर्ष' '4 वर्ष' '2 वर्ष' '1 वर्ष' '6 माह' '4माह' '5 साल' '25 साल'
 '9 साल' '5माह' '6साल' '4Y' '20 YEARS' '40 YEAR' '5Y' '12 YEAR' '2MONTHS'
 '9o"kZ' '5o"kZ' '3o"kZ' '20o"kZ' '25o"kZ' '6MONTH' '10YEARS' '2YRS.'
 '2 YRS.' '2YRS' '1YRS' '8YRS' '2YEAR' '3YEAT' '5 YS' '8 MONTHS' '4 YS'
 '6 MTH' '15 YS' '22' '14' '30YEAR' '28' '12 साल' '1 साल' '15 साल'
 '20 साल' '10 साल' '4 साल']
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dirty" values?

Comment: Dirty value means values in that column is not in the way that it should be. @NYC CODER

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this yourself? Right now you have a requirements dump and a request for someone to write code for you. That's off-topic for SO.

Comment: @AbhishekGoel. I refer you to site rules: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. How can we know what you tried if you don't show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think regex could be your friend here, which Pandas has support for:

play around with something like:

```
df['YrsExp'] = df['YrsExp'].extract(r'(\d+)\s*[y|Y]')
```

and .where() to cap values at 10

```
df['YrsExp'] = df['YrsExp'].where(df < 11, 10)
```

then you can use something like .fillna() to fill values that didn't match your regex:

```
df['YrsExp'] = df['YrsExp'].fillna(0)
```

all these are built-in with Pandas, so be sure to check out the docs

Comment: I would recommend not posting an answer when OP has shown zero effort on their part

Comment: okay, new to posting answers. I'll find out what the standards are

Comment: Your answer is perfectly fine on its own, and will likely not receive any negative feedback. It's really more about the question. We don't want to encourage "give me teh codez" type of question. OP clearly either did not read the instructions, or did not bother following them. Not your fault.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.